# Conditional null not null in a select statement column - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, multiple-columns, conditional-statements

Please take a look at this and let me know the possible solution?

Data to be shown from the table:

```
select a,b,d,e from table xyz.
```

- when c is null show d with value

or

- when c is not null show e with value

Data required:

Data looks like this

```
a b  c          d e 
1 2  null         2
1 2  not null   2
```

From the above data, if c is null, display d = b else e = b.

How to write a proper SQL query for the above conditions, as I tried case it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to try again. Specs like this from customers are excusable...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN d ELSE e END
```

The bit about display d = b else e = b leads me to believe you may also be trying to compare **NULL** and **NOT NULL** values.

It's important to understand that SQL **NULL** means "Unknown" and therefore a comparison cannot take place between a known value and an unknown value.

In this case I suggest the use of [Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to change the value when it is NULL to something comparable that will not affect your logic.

```
Coalesce(d, 0) = b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN d ELSE e END
```

Comment: You're missing a keyword. The correct syntax here is: `SELECT CASE WHEN c IS NULL THEN d ELSE e END`